# Scraper using Goutte without '<br>'

Tags: web-scraping, goutte

In the original page

```
"trader and bla........... <b>have come across</b> ............blabla"
```

In my scraping result

```
"trader and bla........... <b>have</b> <br> <b>come across</b> ............blabla"
```

The problem is: I want to get the value in tag `<b>` where that value is at least has 3 words.  So, I should be able to take the value `have come across`, but I can not get it because `have` and `come across` located not in one tag . How can I get scraping result same as the original page?

Comment: Please [edit] your question adding what have you tried.

Comment: thanks, I have repaired it, I hope you understand

Comment: A quick solution would be that you sanitize what you're getting.

Comment: Sanitize with delete the <br> ? It is not working,  the value 'have' and 'come across' still not in one tag <b>..

Comment: `str_replace('  ', ' ', strip_tags($text));`

Comment: @SebastiánPalma, remember that [comments are temporary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), you can add and answer instead :)

Comment: Thanks @MauricioAriasOlave, I didn't do it because I hadn't news from the author of the question.